# Как уменьшить количество require?

Tags: javascript, node.js

У меня есть:

```
const en = require('../../localization/en.json');
const ru = require('../../localization/ru.json');
const fr = require('../../localization/fr.json');
```

Как всё это вынести куда-нибудь, чтобы не прописывать это в каждом модуле?

Comment: экспортируй один объект с тремя полями

Comment: Для путей можно делать алиасы, используя специальный модуль `module-alias`. https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias

Answer (score 1):

Можно собрать в одном модуле... Например **my_module.js**.

```
const en = require('<путь>/en.json');
const ru = require('<путь>/ru.json');
const fr = require('<путь>/fr.json');

module.expots = {en, ru, fr}
```

Потом выполнять импорт из этого модуля...

```
const {en, ru, fr} = require('<путь>/my_module.js');
```